# Share the session between two websites

Tags: php, session, openid

We are offering a SaaS to website owners where we'll provide the users with interesting offers and track their shopping. Its a rebate model service.

We will offer this service as an IFrame which the site owners will put on their websites.
However, I want the website's original users to be logged into our iframe when they come in?

now, I know that IFrame will be a separate website and hence session is not shared but how would you share the user?

I really want to avoid double login.

1. Is the OpenID a good idea and does our problem lie under this domain?
2. What about Facebook connect (again OpenID).

Thank you

**edit**
Suppose the website has user login already. Can we continue their user's previous logins?

Comment: you can store sessions in the database in php, look it up for more details, then you can connect to the session database from both sites and the sessions will be shared, or alternatively you can redirect the user to a page in the second website upon login, a page which will just serve to start and store session then it will redirect him back to the original page, he won't even feel he's been redirected.

Comment: Al-Kateb can you give me an example of this? Is it recommended security-wise? Suppose, the website doesnt want to share his own database with our service then what is the method available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternatively to OpenID you could create your own Single Sign On Service

Comment: Is there a blue print to creating such a service? I know I have seen some around the internet.

Comment: have a look at CAS, it's an open source SSO solution with PHP client libs available.